# How do I remove trailing emdashes in XSLT?

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

i am working on a xslt 2.0 with replace function and trying to do a xml to text conversion. I am trying to drop an em-dash (—) from conversion if it is present at the end of an xml tag.

e.g

```
<abc> Hello World —</abc>
```

should be output as

```
Hello World
```

but if em dash is present anywhere else , it should be retained, eg.

```
<abc> Hello —World </abc>
```

should be output as

```
Hello —World
```

What i have tried:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
<xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'—\s\*&lt;','')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

but it didn't work

so basically `'—\s\*&lt;'` pattern is not working.
i am reading it as emdash followed by any number of spaces and then opening tag, but i think i am wrong somewhere.

Any inputs would be really helpful.

Comment: Please provide more information. That is, post source XML, a complete XSLT stylesheet and both the actual and desired XML output. Then I'm sure we'll be able to help.

Comment: By the way -- it's better to ask "how do I do X?" than "how do I do X using Y?" -- so, "How do I remove trailing emdashes in XSLT?" would be a better question than "How do I remove trailing emdashes in XSLT using replace() and regexes?" -- the latter presumes a specific answer, thus beggaring the question. (In this particular case, it's a _good_ answer, but still not great practice from an asking-good-questions perspective).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks Charles . I liked your suggestion and have changed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide enough information to diagnose the problem, but I think I can guess. Your problem is that you misunderstood how an XSLT processor "sees" an XML document.

**XML Trees**

When you provide a source XML file to your XSLT processor, it is parsed by an XML parser (which is fairly independent of your XSLT processor). The parser fufils a range of different tasks (for example, it could normalize whitespace characters) but the most important thing is: it constructs an abstract *model* of the source XML, a so-called **tree**. In XSLT, this tree model is called **XDM**. So, when the XSLT processor finally gets to see the XML document, it is an abstract tree.

This is relevant because the tree model consists of nodes that do not have the tags `<` and `>` to mark the start and end of an element. That is why you cannot find them with a regular expression.

**How, then, to find dashes at the end of a string?**

The template you mention matches text nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
```

To find dashes that are at the end of a string, use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'-\s*$','')"/>
```

This replaces a dash, followed by zero or any number of whitespace characters, followed by the end of the string with an empty string. Note that not only the dash is removed - the whitespaces will be gone, too.

---

It might help to use an external service to test your regexes before using them in XSLT.

Comment: One minor quibble -- whitespace between the emdash and the end of the string should be allowed to be compatible with the regex given in the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right of course- I was about to edit my answer already ;)

Comment: *nod*. As it stands, I think your answer is now a full superset of mine; +1, and retracting the competition.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It was not my intention to have you delete your answer of course - but thanks for being so generous.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Thanks for the answer and sorry for not being that elaborate .Your answer completely solved my purpose

Comment: @anurag You are welcome, I am looking forward to answering your next question ;-).